# Tweet to someone using Twitter API v 1.1

Tags: twitter

I can update my own status using https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update or https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media

But I can not see any resource to tweet to someone else. How I can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tweet to someone you just need to "mention" him in your tweet text like: `@maxdec hey dude what's up?`. So you just use the `statuses/update` endpoint.